# How to fix black screen of Ubuntu after I on my laptop?

Tags: boot, reboot

I am using Compaq Pressario CQ40. While I was trying to fix the problem of touchpad, I opened up `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and typed the commands:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
MatchProduct "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver "synaptics"
Option "AreaTopEdge" "50"
```

After that I rebooted it, but Ubuntu stopped working. It just shows me a black screen.
Neither I can reinstall or nor can I login to my previous one.

Comment: Have you tried the following: sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg ? Hit Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get a prompt and try this if it will allow.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options depending on your skill set.

1. If the other options fail you may reinstall. It'll fix it all.
2. This method will take some skill but you seem to have skill so... Hit ctrl+alt+F1 when you're at the black screen. This should get you a login prompt. Login. Using Vi, Vim or whatever **sudo Vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf**   and just delete your latest entry. That ought to fix it.